# Need help in writing query to het total and unique count

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have one table where I want to retrieve count of user who visited the page ,one is total count and another unique count.

**total count**- if user X visit page thrice and Y visit page twice then total count should be 5
& **unique count**- if user X visit page thrice and Y visit page twice then total count should be 2 (counting unique user)

table structure as follows

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  joveuser varchar(64)  DEFAULT NULL,
  page text  NOT NULL,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  time_on_page int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  country varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

Here joveuser will be the user and page will be accessing page.

below are the insert queries

```
insert into xyz values('aaa','abc','2021-01-25',25,'CA');
insert into xyz values('bbb','def','2021-04-23',322,'unknown');
insert into xyz values('aaa','atgh','2021-02-12',15,'US');
insert into xyz values('aaa','fgh','2021-03-25',56,'unknown');
insert into xyz values('bbb','tyud','2021-02-14',85,'unknown');
insert into xyz values('ccc','jjj','2021-05-01',125,'US');
```

sample data as below

```html
<table>
XYZ
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>joveuser</th>
<th>page</th>
<th>timestamp</th>
<th>time_on_page</th>
<th>country</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>abc</td>
<td>2021-01-25</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>CA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>def</td>
<td>2021-04-23</td>
<td>322</td>
<td>unknown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>atgh</td>
<td>2021-02-12</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>US</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>fgh</td>
<td>2021-03-25</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>unknown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>tyud</td>
<td>2021-02-14</td>
<td>85</td>
<td>unknown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>ccc</td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>2021-05-01</td>
<td>125</td>
<td>US</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

sample output like below

```html
<table>
output
<thead>
<tr>
<th>totalcount</th>
<th>uniquecount</th>
<th>country</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>unknown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>other countries</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here in output total visit is 6 but there same user visit so unique count is 3. I have written queries but not getting expected output.

Need help in query to get above output.

Comment: COUNT(user) AND COUNT(DISTINCT user) respectively.

Comment: @Akina I have already tried this but the challenge is for country unknown I need separate count and  other all countries one count. Is that possible? Any suggestion

Comment: *I have already tried this but the challenge is for country unknown I need separate count and other all countries one count. Is that possible?* If so then adjust your desired output - there is no `country` column in it at all. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d1233bbe94f6923cd2adceeaef6b45a

Comment: @Akina edited sample output ,rest countries should be in other countries and unknown as one count,Should I go for union all?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(joveuser) totalcount, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT joveuser) uniquecount, 
       CASE country WHEN 'unknown' 
                    THEN 'unknown'
                    ELSE 'other countries'
                    END country
FROM test
GROUP BY 3
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6773e7e1b32a94c5b22c81cc1edd030